# Transmission fluid for 2012 rav4 4 cyl

Tags: toyota, transmission, automatic-transmission, transmission-fluid

I am looking for transmission fluid for a 2012 rav4 4cyl that is sold in Canada.

I have come across [this Castrol Transmax fluid](https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/castrol-transmax-full-synthetic-multi-vehicle-atf-0289195p.html) that is sold in Canadian Tire.

It says (zoom in on the picture) that it is suitable for Toyota Stepped transmissions.

Does that mean it is suitable for my specific 2012 rav4 transmission.

I really want to avoid paying the prices at the dealership.

Answer (score 0):

Toyota does not approval of any "all makes, all model" "universal" transmission fluid. But it at the dealer. Not worth it to use a universal fluid